# Discrete number does not work well in DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

The code below works fine.

```
 DN[n_Integer] := n; n = 0;
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == Cos[t] + a[t], x[0] == a[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, {a[t] -> a[t] + DN[n], n = n + 1}]}, x[t], {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> {a[t], n, DN}]
```

But it does not work if I try to replace NDSolve with DSolve , and the warning says "Equation or list of equations expected instead of WhenEvent..."
How shall I correct the code if I wish to insist on DSolve.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica v12.2(Thanks  @cvgmt's comment ) `WhenEvent` only works for numerical solvers like `NDSolve,...`, not with `DSolve`. In newer versions `DSolve`is allowed.

I'm wondering why your example works!

`DN[]` is an external function, shouldn't be redefined in `DiscreteVariables`.
Same with `n`.

Try

```
DN[n_ ] := n; 
sol = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == Cos[t] + a[t], x[0] == a[0] == n[0] == 0, 
WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, {a[t] -> a[t] + DN[n[t]], n[t] -> n[t] + 1}]}, 
{x,a,n} , {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> {a , n }];
Plot[ Through[sol[t]], {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: According to the document, `WhenEvent expressions can be used in NDSolve, NDSolveValue, ParametricNDSolve, ParametricNDSolveValue, DSolve, and DSolveValue. `  For example, `DSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.95 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks, my fault. My Mathematica version is v12.2 and here `WhenEvent` only defined for `NDSoleve&Co`

Comment: +1, Your code work when we replace `NDSolveValue` to `DSolveValue` in  v12.3 and  v13.3.1.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Thanks a lot. Now the only question is why my original code works fine in NDSlove while not in DSolve. It seems WhenEvent works in a different way in DSolve than in NDSolve.

Comment: @metroidman I think I can explain why `NDSolve` is fooled by `DiscreteVariables -> {a[t], n, DN}`. According to the **Details** section of document of `DiscreteVariables`:  `{v, vmin, vmax}` means `v` has range `vmin<=v<=vmax`. So, `{a[t], n, DN}` just happens to be something meaning `n<=a[t]<=DN`. (In principle the non-numeric `DN` should still trigger a warning, I think this is arguably a bug. ) Actually if one writes e.g. `DiscreteVariables -> {n, a[t], DN}`, `NDSolve` will spit out a warning and fail.

Comment: @xzczd, that is a great finding. Appreciated for your explaination.